# Ruby,Railsのバージョンアップに伴うcloud9サーバ起動時のエラー

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, aws-cloud9

Ruby on Railsのアプリで以下の作業を行ったところ、開発環境（AWS Cloud9）内でサーバが立ち上がらずエラーになってしまいます。
エラーメッセージを調べても、糸口がいまいちつかめず解決に至らずにいます。

もし、問題ありそうな可能性という程度でも何かアドバイス頂ければ、この上なくありがたいです。

何卒よろしくお願いいたします

#### 実施したこと

以下へそれぞれバージョンアップデートを実施

- ruby '**2.3.4**'　→　ruby '**2.5.9**'
- rails '**4.2.5**'　→　rails ‘**4.2.8**'

#### 開発環境

AWS Cloud9

#### 事象

開発環境内でサーバが立ち上らず、以下のエラーメッセージになる

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

        24: from bin/rails:9:in `<main>'

        23: from bin/rails:9:in `require'

        22: from /home/ubuntu/アプリ名/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'

        21: from /home/ubuntu/アプリ名/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'

        20: from /home/ubuntu/アプリ名/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'

        19: from /home/ubuntu/アプリ名/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'

        18: from /home/ubuntu/アプリ名/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'

        17: from /home/ubuntu/アプリ名/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.8/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:78:in `start'

        16: from /home/ubuntu/アプリ名/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.8/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:139:in `log_to_stdout'

        15: from /home/ubuntu/アプリ名/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rack-1.6.13/lib/rack/server.rb:337:in `wrapped_app'

        14: from /home/ubuntu/アプリ名/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.8/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:61:in `app'

        13: from /home/ubuntu/アプリ名/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rack-1.6.13/lib/rack/server.rb:209:in `app'

        12: from /home/ubuntu/アプリ名/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rack-1.6.13/lib/rack/server.rb:300:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'

        11: from /home/ubuntu/アプリ名/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rack-1.6.13/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'

        10: from /home/ubuntu/アプリ名/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rack-1.6.13/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'

         9: from /home/ubuntu/アプリ名/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rack-1.6.13/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'

         8: from /home/ubuntu/environment/アプリ名/config.ru:in `<main>'

         7: from /home/ubuntu/environment/アプリ名/config.ru:in `new'

         6: from /home/ubuntu/アプリ名/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rack-1.6.13/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'

         5: from /home/ubuntu/アプリ名/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rack-1.6.13/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'

         4: from /home/ubuntu/environment/アプリ名/config.ru:6:in `block in <main>'

         3: from /home/ubuntu/アプリ名/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'

         2: from /home/ubuntu/アプリ名/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'

         1: from /home/ubuntu/アプリ名/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'


/home/ubuntu/アプリ名/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require': no implicit conversion from nil to integer (TypeError)
```

**config.ru:**

```
# This file is used by Rack-based servers to start the application.　　
　　
require ::File.expand_path('../config/environment', __FILE__)  
run Rails.application　　
　　
require 'gctools/oobgc'　　
if defined?(Unicorn::HttpRequest)　　
  use GC::OOB::UnicornMiddleware　　
end
```

Comment: エラーメッセージを見てみると、

`4: from /home/ubuntu/environment/アプリ名/config.ru:6:in `block in <main>'`

この行が自分自身のコード（ライブラリではないコード）の中で一番エラーに近いものとなっています。
`config.ru`というファイルはすべてのRailsアプリに必ず含まれるものです。一度コメント欄に内容を貼り付けていただいてよろしいでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/tmm1/gctools/issues/16

こちらのissueが参考になりそうです。
基本的には、'gctools/oobgc'の作者は「Ruby2.5ではGCの仕組みが変わったから、このgemは削除してよい」と言っているようです。
`config.ru`の下4行を削除してみてはいかがでしょうか。

Comment: ありがとうございます！！
参考にさせていただき、進めてみたいと思います！

Answer (score 0):

自己解決しました。
rubyのバージョンに対してrailsバージョンが低すぎたようです